# Adding two .sqlite DB into a list and showing by adapter

Tags: android, database, list, sqlite, listview

I have two databases .sqlite in Android.
*productosdb.sqlite* and *entradas.sqlite* with one table each.
In *productosdb* I have the table `"entradas"={id,cod1,cod2,descrip,present,pale}` and in the other  `"entradas"={id,idref(that is cod1 already saved from the other table),cant,vto}`

I want to show all items of table `"entradas"` but giving to the adapter a list that has all fields of both tables. When I get a row from table `"entradas"` I get the message `idrefto search the other the missing fields`. Something is not working. Here's some of the code:

```
private List<ProductoSUMADO> listasumada = new LinkedList<ProductoSUMADO>();  

Producto temporalProducto = new Producto();  

List<ProductoConVencimiento> temporalEntrada = new LinkedList<ProductoConVencimiento>();

String asd = bundle.getString("codigo");

temporalProducto = managerdb.getProductoPorCodigoBarras(asd);

String sss = temporalProducto.getCodprod();
temporalEntrada = db.getProductosPorIDRef(sss);

for (int pos = 0; pos < temporalEntrada.size(); pos++)
{
   ProductoSUMADO p = new ProductoSUMADO(temporalProducto.getCodbar()),
   temporalProducto.getCodprod(),
   temporalProducto.getDescrip(),
   temporalProducto.getPresent(),
   temporalProducto.getPale(),
   temporalEntrada.get(pos).getCant(),
   temporalEntrada.get(pos).getVto(),
   temporalEntrada.get(pos).getNotas());

   listasumada.add(p);
}

CustomAdapter2 adapter = new CustomAdapter2(this, listasumada);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Maybe you understand what I want to do and show another way to do this.

Comment: I think for your case it wasn't enough to post this code snippet. There are a lot of places were soming is doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Just create one database and two tables "productos" and "entradas"
then you will be able to JOIN data using rawQuery.

Learn more about SQLite here: [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

it has examples so you can test it!

Join example:

```
String MY_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM table_a a INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.id=b.other_id WHERE b.property_id=?";
db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[]{String.valueOf(propertyId)});
```